# Как работает ограничение обобщения классом использующим его? Зачем вообще нужна эта строчка и как она работает?

Tags: c#, классы

```
public class Comma<T> : Point where T : Comma<T> {}
```

Содержимое классов Comma и Point не влияет на результат. Код работает и взят из книги по оптимизации с помощью синглтонов.

Comment: что конкретно не понятно то?

Comment: Это аналог плюсового [Сrtp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: Адовая штука, я правда не понял зачем ее использовать, да по читабельности кода она бьет сильно.